# SQL Server saída com 5 resultados

Tags: sql-server

Estou tentando executar uma QUERY na qual me traz o resultado da data das ultimas 5 semanas passadas com base na data atual exemplo, o usuário seleciona do dia 20/12/2022 e a saída me traz

```
13/12/2022
06/12/2022
29/11/2022
22/11/2022
15/11/2022
```

fiz uma QUERY que me trouxe o resultado, porém parece que não é uma boa prática

```
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -1, '20/12/2022')
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -2, '20/12/2022')
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -3, '20/12/2022')
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -4, '20/12/2022')
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -5, '20/12/2022')
```

Tem alguma possibilidade de um otimização, melhoria deste?

Sou Junior na área de T.I então desde já agradeço a paciência e compreensão de todos!

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Gere uma sequencia artificial de 1 a N e gere sua sequencia de datas. Em Oracle usaria  dual e connect by no SqlServer não sei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível gerar a sequencia de datas de várias maneiras, como na sua pergunta quer gerar isso numa única *query*, pode usar um *query* com CTE ([*Common Table Expression*](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)), fazendo um único `UNION` mas limitando a quantidade de datas usando `WHERE`, assim por exemplo:

```
WITH Resultado AS (
  SELECT DATA = DATEADD(WEEK, -1, CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/20/2022'))
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATA = DATEADD(WEEK, -1, DATA)
    FROM Resultado
   WHERE DATA > DATEADD(WEEK, -5, CONVERT(DATETIME,'12/20/2022'))
) 
SELECT DATA
  FROM Resultado
```

No script usei a data no format MM/DD/YYYY, mas pode ser convertido. O primeiro `SELECT DATA =` gera a primeira data, o segundo `SELECT`, já dentro do `UNION ALL` vai gerar as datas seguintes, limitado ao `WHERE`. Note que, de certa forma pode gerar resultados quase infinitos, isso porque o segundo `SELECT` é "recursivo" por assim dizer, então atenção ao `WHERE` para limitar o resultado. Para evitar problemas de performace ou carga, pode ainda limitar o resultado, adicionando ao final da query `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 4)`, isso porque, como quer gerar 4 datas, a "máxima recursão" será de 4 (a primeira data é gerada no primeiro `SELECT`), evitando os problemas que citei.

Pode ver funcionando aqui: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/176648)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado pelo seu tempo e sua explicação detalhada me ajudou muito!